# Confidence intervals for chi square goodness of fit

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit

I'm having trouble figuring this out. I know that you calculate the confidence interval same as you would for a proportion, $p_i= P \pm 1.96 \sqrt{(P(1-P))/N}$, but in my notes it says:

> calculate interval for each category
>   Calculate the proportion Pi0 given H0 is true
>   We want to look at the ratio of these two values (actual proportion/expected proportion)
>   Calculate for high, center, and low values to to create a confidence interval (using above formula)

What I'm confused about it how that ratio plays into any of it. I can use the formula at the top to get an interval, but I'm confused what I'm supposed to do with that ratio.

So in an example,

My observed value is .35, my n is 100... (an expected proportion would be .25) 
Just using the confidence interval formula at the top (for 95%) I got a CI of .257, .443

Where was that ratio supposed to come in? What am I missing?